# How to change proprietary video driver using the command line?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, video

My laptop computer has a Nvidia video card and runs Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit. During an upgrade yesterday it seemed as a new Nvidia driver version 304 (if I remember correct) was installed. After upgrade and reboot, I opened the Additional Driver tool and found that the Nvidia driver version 304 was in use. So far so good.

However, the Additional Driver tool also reported that there existed a Nvidia driver version 319 and that this driver version was recommended. I then selected to change to this recommended driver, the driver was downloaded and installed, I rebooted the system and ended up with a black screen and a command shell.

How to change proprietary Nvidia video driver using the command line and revert back to the previous version that worked on my system?

(A second question: How can it be that a video driver that apparently does not work was recommended?)

Comment: are you interested in also changing version or just seeing them?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Update: For 18.04 and later you need to use `ubuntu-drivers`.
See `ubuntu-drivers -h` for syntax.

### Ubuntu 12.04 (for later versions, see other answers)

You can use `jockey-text` to disable and enable Nvidia drivers in Ubuntu.

For example:

- Run `jockey-text --list` to get the list of available options.
- Run `sudo jockey-text -d xorg:nvidia_304` to remove the 304 driver.
- Run `sudo jockey-text -e xorg:nvidia_304` to enable the same driver.
- Run `jockey-text --help` to see the help manual.

Comment: what about in 13.10? I don't have a tool called `jockey`.

Comment: jockey-text is provided by jockey-common: `sudo apt-get install jockey-common`

Comment: 14.04 (maybe 13.10 also) replaced `jockey-common` with `ubuntu-drivers-common` which has the `ubuntu-drivers` executable that works differently.

Comment: what about changing driver now that we have the version?

Answer (score 59):

As per this [Ubuntu Community Help Wiki Page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia#Installation_without_X_.2F_from_the_console), Ubuntu 14.04+ is different:

**Ubuntu 14.04 and up**

The jockey-text command was removed with the release of Ubuntu 14.04. You can now use ubuntu-drivers to get the list of packages for each driver, and then install the packages using apt-get. For example:

`sudo ubuntu-drivers devices`

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==

vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000DDAsv000017AAsd000021D1bc03sc00i00
model    : GF106GLM [Quadro 2000M]
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
driver   : nvidia-304-updates - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-304 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-331 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-331-updates - distro non-free
```

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-331`

**Ubuntu 12.04 (same as mikewhatever's answer)**

If you need to change drivers without the use of the X GUI, perhaps because those drivers are not installed, you can with the jockey-text command. For example:

```
jockey-text --help
jockey-text -l
jockey-text -e xorg:nvidia_current
```

Comment: I get `ubuntu-drivers: command not found` if I try to run `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` on 14.04.

Comment: run `apt install ubuntu-drivers-common` to install `ubuntu-drivers` first.

Comment: He didn't ask how to install a new driver.  He asked how to activate an already installed driver: "evert back to the previous version that worked on my system"

Comment: Facing same challenge. I have login in tty2 and want to switch my driver . By sudo ubuntu-drivers command, i can see 4 options. I want to switch driver from nouveau to nvidia-driver-440 (i want to switch, not install as these 4 are already installed). Can you help me to switch command

Comment: what about changing driver now that we have the version?

Comment: @Mubasher and @charlie-parker , from looking at all tutorials on the topic, the `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-123` method is what actually selects the driver as well. You need to reboot your system after that. Then, to verify, run `nvidia-smi` to see which driver version is being used for NVIDIA. If that does not work for whatever reason, there is also the command `ubuntu-drivers install nvidia-driver-123`. See `ubuntu-drivers -h` for more info.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem using 304/319 drivers from repositories, Nvidia has proprietary drivers on their website, installed from there they actually work quite well, I used this manual to remove remaining drivers and install the correct one directly from Nvidia.

http://www.beginninglinux.com/home/graphics-drivers/install-nvidia-custom-driver-on-ubuntu-12-04

Make sure you pay attention to everything, especially make sure that in `/etc/default/grub` line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` contains `nomodeset`, otherwise Nvidia driver does not work.

Also if proprietary drivers do not work and you are stuck in command line, you may always uninstall Nvidia drivers and install the default nouveau driver.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge nvidia-*
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```

Comment: sudo: stop: command not found

Comment: what about changing driver now that we have the version?

Answer (score 4):

Nowadays (2023), you can use `ubuntu-drivers` both for looking at available driver versions, and installing them.
For example, you can

- get the list of available drivers:

  ```
  ubuntu-drivers list
  ```
- install the recommended drivers:

  ```
  sudo ubuntu-drivers install
  ```
- install a specific version from the list:

  ```
  sudo ubuntu-drivers install nvidia:535
  ```

You can read more at the official [NVIDIA drivers installation](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/nvidia-drivers-installation) guide.

Comment: This is the most up-to-date answer on this page.

Answer (score 1):

Besides (I know this does not really answer the question), if you are stuck without menu or have a window manager that does not integrate, the ubuntu menu, in **Ubuntu 18.04** (and probably most other versions), the graphical frontend where you can choose the Proprietary Drivers can be started via

`software-properties-gtk` . Of course you need a working X Server to start and use the tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can also download the .sh file from nvidia then follow the steps:

- First press control+alt+f1 - to exit GUI mode

  - sudo service gdm stop (on ubuntu)
  - navigate to the folder you downloaded nvidia drivers
  - ./nvidia.drivers.sh
  - sudo reboot after install