# How do I change the default graphics driver from Intel to Nvidia in Ubuntu Gnome 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, graphics

I am using Toshiba Satellite C50 A2012, with Ubuntu 14.04 and an Nvidia graphics card. How do I change my graphics to Nvidia from Intel graphic card?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/335285/how-to-change-proprietary-video-driver-using-the-command-line Should help you.

Answer (score 0):

To open the GUI, use the command `software-properties-gtk`. Kudos @Muru for the command!

Comment: Is `jockey` still available in 14.04? I thought it was discarded in favour of the Drivers section in Software Sources (`software-properties-gtk`)?

Comment: It's a long trip via Software Centre (Edit->Sources). Or `software-properties-gtk --open-tab 4`.

Comment: Wow, not easy! Okay, will change my answer, thanks!