# Switching between nvdia driver versions on 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I am currently running propriety nvidia drivers 361.42 on Ubuntu 16.04

```
$ dmesg | grep -i nvid
[    4.233238] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  361.42  Tue Mar 22 18:10:58 PDT 2016
```

The card itself is a GTX-960

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM206 [GeForce GTX 960] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GM206 [GeForce GTX 960]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127
    Memory at de000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at df000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_361
```

Unfortunately, a piece of software I am using claims a bug in the driver causes its software to crash and I have been asked to downgrade the driver to 352.79.

It does not simply want to apt-get install this version, however:

```
damien@damien-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
[sudo] password for damien: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nvidia-352 is already the newest version (361.42-0ubuntu2).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
damien@damien-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-352-updates
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nvidia-352-updates
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 4,814 B of archives.
After this operation, 17.4 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 nvidia-352-updates amd64 361.42-0ubuntu2 [4,814 B]
Fetched 4,814 B in 0s (12.4 kB/s)             
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-352-updates.
(Reading database ... 439776 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-352-updates_361.42-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-352-updates (361.42-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up nvidia-352-updates (361.42-0ubuntu2) ...
```

Purging and re-installing seems to automatically select version 361, which is what I want to avoid:

```
damien@damien-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  nvidia-361 nvidia-opencl-icd-361 nvidia-prime nvidia-settings
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nvidia-352 nvidia-361 nvidia-opencl-icd-361 nvidia-prime nvidia-settings
0 to upgrade, 5 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 866 kB/77.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 339 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 nvidia-prime amd64 0.8.2 [11.1 kB]
Get:2 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 nvidia-settings amd64 361.42-0ubuntu1 [855 kB]
Fetched 866 kB in 2s (324 kB/s)          
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-361.
(Reading database ... 439200 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-361_361.42-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-361 (361.42-0ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-352.
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-352_361.42-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-352 (361.42-0ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-opencl-icd-361.
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-opencl-icd-361_361.42-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-opencl-icd-361 (361.42-0ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-prime.
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-prime_0.8.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-prime (0.8.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-settings.
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-settings_361.42-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-settings (361.42-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160415-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Setting up nvidia-361 (361.42-0ubuntu2) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-361/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-361/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_egl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-361/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-361/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_EGL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_egl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/nvidia-361/glamor.conf to provide /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/glamoregl.conf (glamor_conf) in auto mode
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia-361
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
Adding system user `nvidia-persistenced' (UID 123) ...
Adding new group `nvidia-persistenced' (GID 130) ...
Adding new user `nvidia-persistenced' (UID 123) with group `nvidia-persistenced' ...
Not creating home directory `/'.
Loading new nvidia-361-361.42 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 4.4.0-22-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.4.0-22-generic
Done.

nvidia_361:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-22-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia_361_modeset.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-22-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia_361_uvm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-22-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
Setting up nvidia-352 (361.42-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up nvidia-opencl-icd-361 (361.42-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up nvidia-prime (0.8.2) ...
Setting up nvidia-settings (361.42-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-22-generic
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
```

How can I safely downgrade to this version of the driver?  I cannot simply remove all nvidia drivers and re-install because nouveau does not seem to work at all with my hardware (I had to install Ubuntu as the server version then covert it to a desktop later).

Comment: what did you end up doing? did you really just uninstall all of them and then reboot? you can't select one driver?

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25663/how-to-get-the-version-of-my-nvidia-driver, https://askubuntu.com/questions/335285/how-to-change-proprietary-video-driver-using-the-command-line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ubuntu 16.04 `nvidia-352` is just a transitional package for `nvidia-361`.
Fortunately `nvidia-352` is available from the Proprietary GPU drivers PPA.
Download the following `nvidia-352.79` realated packages from the PPA :

[libcuda1-352_352.79-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+files/libcuda1-352_352.79-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2_amd64.deb)
[nvidia-352_352.79-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+files/nvidia-352_352.79-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2_amd64.deb)
[nvidia-libopencl1-352_352.79-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+files/nvidia-libopencl1-352_352.79-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2_amd64.deb)
[nvidia-opencl-icd-352_352.79-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+files/nvidia-opencl-icd-352_352.79-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2_amd64.deb)

But first you should check whether the latest stable drivers `nvidia-364` can solve the problem.

Remove the NVIDIA drivers 361 - open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Select the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the operating system.

Important : Set a <kbd>Space</kbd> between the last character in the `linux` line and `nouveau.modeset=0`.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and password and then execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-364
sudo reboot
```

In case these drivers do not work - open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Select the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the operating system.

Important : Set a <kbd>Space</kbd> between the last character in the `linux` line and `nouveau.modeset=0`.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and password and then execute :

```
cd /<path-to-the-folder-which-contains-the-.deb-files-you-have-downloaded-before>  

sudo dpkg -i libcuda1-352_352.79-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i nvidia-352_352.79-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2_amd64.deb  
sudo dpkg -i nvidia-libopencl1-352_352.79-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2_amd64.deb  
sudo dpkg -i nvidia-opencl-icd-352_352.79-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2_amd64.deb  

sudo reboot
```

Note : In case that you get a dependency error, execute `apt install -f` after each single error.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but the nvidia-352 package seems to force the installation of 361.  I have updated my question with this information.  Incidentally lightdm did not start with noveau, even with the modeset change as instructed.

Comment: Thanks, it solves my problem, but there is one remain issue: nvidia-libopencl1-352_352.79-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2_amd64.deb does not install: 

dpkg: regarding nvidia-libopencl1-352_352.79-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2_amd64.deb containing nvidia-libopencl1-352:
 nvidia-libopencl1-352 conflicts with libopencl1
  ocl-icd-libopencl1:amd64 provides libopencl1 and is present and installed.

Comment: Incidentally, 364 does not solve my problem, but the older drivers do.

Comment: @Damien : I am glad to read that you could solve the problem. The conflict message is nothing you should worry about - both packages are having the same functionality. You can either keep the ocl-icd-libopencl1 package installed, or you can uninstall it by executing : sudo apt purge ocl-icd-libopencl1 and - afterwards install nvidia-libopencl1 : sudo dpkg -i nvidia-libopencl1-352_352.79-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2_amd64.deb :)

Comment: so there is no way to select a driver except just uninstalling all of them and then only installing the one you and then rebooting?