# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes at Login Screen, but I can SSH to it

Tags: 18.04, login

I'm new to Ubuntu, and after about a week, after a restart, it is freezing on the login screen. The keyboard doesn't seem to work and mouse doesn't move (they're not at fault, I entered the Boot menu and they both worked there). Before this, I had autologin and it would show the shell and the "unlock the keying box", and froze there (wouldn't take any commands) - I disabled autologin for now. The system is working, I can see the clock adjusting correctly.

At the same time, I can SSH with Putty from my windows machine and run any commands there.

I have

- Ubuntu 4.18.0-17.
- Nvidia RTX 2080 TI with 418 driver,
- AMD CPU,
- 64 Gb Ram.

I had no issues until today.

Comment: Have you tried using another display manager (such as SDDM or LightDM) temporarily?

Comment: I agree, this is a common problem with `gdm3`. Try installing lightdm: `sudo apt install lightdm` and then when you are prompted, select lightdm as your display manager. If lightdm is already installed, run the following command and then choose lightdm as the display manager when you are prompted: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

Comment: Also, please see this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/699384/167115 and install the driver that is listed as "recommended"

Comment: Also, my keyboard and mouse work at the boot menu but I have to unplug and plug them back in after boot sometimes.

Comment: Thank you @mchid, installing lightdm fixed it!!

Comment: Should I do anything else about gdm3,or just leave it like this?

Comment: @ChrisFotache You can try reinstalling gdm3. Moreover, your latest revision looks like an answer. Consider writing that as an answer.