# 20.04 crashing on dpkg --configure -a

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, dpkg, crash

PC keeps crashing when I'm trying to fix dpkg by running dpkg --configure -a
It crashed and went to basic video so I tried to downgrade the nvidia driver to 460 (495 has been working fine, didn't update anything else)  but apt is locked and everytime I try to fix it it crashes; black screen.
I've tried from the recovery console as root, same thing.
RTX 2060
Ubuntu 20.04.3

There isn't anything in the logs that I can see. Temperatures seem fine.

This is what is says on the screen when it crashes:

```
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-91-generic
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
Removing old nvidia-495.46 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 495.46
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new nvidia-495.46 DKMS files...
Building for 5.4.0-91-generic 5.4.0-92-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.4.0-91-generic
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saw this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1346300/dpkg-error-processing-package-nvidia-driver-after-install-ubuntu-20-10?rq=1) and thought it migth be worth a go reinstalling gcc.

I booted to live cd and [chroot'd in](https://serverfault.com/questions/857474/install-package-via-apt-from-a-live-cd-to-the-real-system) and [killed apt and removed the apt locks](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/fix-could-not-get-lock-error-ubuntu) bc it was still telling me to fix dpkg.

`sudo apt-get install gcc` said that it was installed but now set to manual.
ran `sudo dpkg --configure -a`  again and, though all the cpu's went to 100 for a worrying amount of time it completed successfully and is now working fine.

**** edit ****

The problem came back and in the end following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1388730/nvidia-modules-failing-when-installing-linux-image-5-4-0-96-generic) removing duplicate drivers seemed to do the trick.