# nvidia modules failing when installing linux-image-5.4.0-96-generic

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, upgrade, kernel

After installing the most recent kernels my system can no longer start the nvidia daemon. A closer inspection shows that NVIDIA modules are missing for `linux-image-5.4.0-96-generic`:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-generic linux-image-5.4.0-96-generic linux-headers-5.4.0-96-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  android-studio-4.1 cuda-command-line-tools-10-2 cuda-compiler-10-2 cuda-cudart-10-2 cuda-cudart-dev-10-2 cuda-cufft-10-2 cuda-cufft-dev-10-2 cuda-cupti-10-2 cuda-cupti-dev-10-2 cuda-curand-10-2
  cuda-curand-dev-10-2 cuda-cusolver-10-2 cuda-cusolver-dev-10-2 cuda-cusparse-10-2 cuda-cusparse-dev-10-2 cuda-documentation-10-2 cuda-driver-dev-10-2 cuda-libraries-10-2 cuda-libraries-dev-10-2
  cuda-memcheck-10-2 cuda-misc-headers-10-2 cuda-npp-10-2 cuda-npp-dev-10-2 cuda-nsight-10-2 cuda-nsight-compute-10-2 cuda-nsight-systems-10-2 cuda-nvcc-10-2 cuda-nvgraph-10-2 cuda-nvgraph-dev-10-2
  cuda-nvjpeg-10-2 cuda-nvjpeg-dev-10-2 cuda-nvml-dev-10-2 cuda-nvprof-10-2 cuda-nvprune-10-2 cuda-nvrtc-10-2 cuda-nvrtc-dev-10-2 cuda-nvtx-10-2 cuda-nvvp-10-2 cuda-samples-10-2 cuda-sanitizer-api-10-2
  cuda-toolkit-10-2 cuda-tools-10-2 cuda-visual-tools-10-2 golang-1.15-go golang-1.15-src golang-1.16-go golang-1.16-src lib32gcc1 libcublas-dev libcublas10 libllvm10:i386 libllvm11 libllvm11:i386
  libmysofa0 libplacebo18 libuv1-dev libxdamage1:i386 nsight-compute-2019.5.0 nsight-systems-2019.5.2 nvidia-modprobe shim
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/11.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 438750 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-5.4.0-96-generic_5.4.0-96.109_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.4.0-96-generic (5.4.0-96.109) over (5.4.0-96.109) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-5.4.0-96-generic_5.4.0-96.109_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-5.4.0-96-generic (5.4.0-96.109) over (5.4.0-96.109) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-generic_5.4.0.96.100_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-generic (5.4.0.96.100) over (5.4.0.96.100) ...
Setting up linux-headers-5.4.0-96-generic (5.4.0-96.109) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.4.0-96-generic
   ...done.
Setting up linux-image-5.4.0-96-generic (5.4.0-96.109) ...
depmod: ERROR: failed to load symbols from /lib/modules/5.4.0-96-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia-modeset.ko: Invalid argument
depmod: ERROR: failed to load symbols from /lib/modules/5.4.0-96-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia-drm.ko: Invalid argument
depmod: ERROR: failed to load symbols from /lib/modules/5.4.0-96-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia-uvm.ko: Invalid argument
depmod: ERROR: failed to load symbols from /lib/modules/5.4.0-96-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko: Invalid argument
Setting up linux-image-generic (5.4.0.96.100) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.4.0-96-generic (5.4.0-96.109) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.4.0-96-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-96-generic
modinfo: ERROR: could not get modinfo from 'nvidia': Invalid argument
modinfo: ERROR: could not get modinfo from 'nvidia_drm': Invalid argument
modinfo: ERROR: could not get modinfo from 'nvidia_modeset': Invalid argument
modinfo: ERROR: could not get modinfo from 'nvidia_uvm': Invalid argument
depmod: ERROR: failed to load symbols from /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_cIT7Rf/lib/modules/5.4.0-96-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia-modeset.ko: Invalid argument
depmod: ERROR: failed to load symbols from /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_cIT7Rf/lib/modules/5.4.0-96-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia-drm.ko: Invalid argument
depmod: ERROR: failed to load symbols from /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_cIT7Rf/lib/modules/5.4.0-96-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia-uvm.ko: Invalid argument
depmod: ERROR: failed to load symbols from /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_cIT7Rf/lib/modules/5.4.0-96-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko: Invalid argument
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-1061-oracle
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-1061-oracle
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-96-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-96-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-94-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-94-generic
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
```

To get around this I'm currently just running on 5.4.0-94-generic. Is anyone else running into this issue? Should I just wait for the next update?

#### Additional info per comments

- I am running Ubuntu 20.04.3.
- `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` are all up-to-date.
- The latest NVIDIA driver I have installed is `nvidia-driver-495`.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release? What are the Nvidia drivers?

Comment: The 5.4 kernel was released some time ago. Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Updated Ubuntu version to the end of question details.

Comment: Is your ubuntu system updated? Please check for updates and make sure that you're running the **latest** version of ubuntu. Then try again.

Comment: 20.04.3 uses the 5.11 kernel. Are you intentionally installing an older kernel? Perhaps I’m misunderstanding the goal of the question … 

Comment: @matigo 20.04 uses both 5.4 and 5.13 now. It depends on HWE stack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hmm... Seems like your `dkms` files for NVIDIA are corrupted. Try following these steps:

1. Remove the `dkms` file for NVIDIA.

   ```
   sudo rm -r /var/lib/dkms/nvidia
   ```
2. Reinstall `dkms` to regenerate the file:

   ```
   sudo apt install --reinstall dkms
   ```
3. Purge the Nvidia drivers:

   ```
   sudo apt purge nvidia-*
   ```
4. Now, reinstall the recommended drivers using:

   ```
   sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
   ```

The above will regenerate your `dkms.conf` file.

---

1. Reinstall the kernel packages:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-generic linux-image-5.4.0-96-generic linux-headers-5.4.0-96-generic linux-generic
   ```
2. Update Grub:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
3. Update Initramfs:

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```

That's it! 
Good luck!

Comment: Have to say I was skeptical at first. But this did it!

Comment: @Cescante Awesome! Glad it's working as expected. Have fun!

Comment: For the record, "ubuntu-drivers autoinstall" caused my desktop to go black... ssh'ing remotely showed some kind of 100% CPU lockup happening... couldn't break out of it and had to restore from a backup. Maybe it would be safer to run this from a CLI without the desktop loaded?