# Trying to select NVidia driver version 530 in Ubuntu 22.04 results in "empty window with ok button"

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04

When trying to select NVidia driver version 530 from the "Software & Updates" settings, I'm getting this window:

[image]

Most likely, it wants to tell me that something went wrong, because it automatically switches back to the previously selected driver version.

Is this a known issue with a work-around?

Comment: What's kernel release are you using? I'm using `5.19.0-43-generic` for now. My machine couldn't even boot using `5.19.0-45-generic` normal mode. Got same error when trying switch nvidia driver. Couldn't select `X.org` too, but got error message with text about kernel dependencies. Only switch back to `5.19.0-43-generic` helped

Comment: I booted `5.19.0-43-generic` in normal mode, updated to `nvidia-driver-530 (proprietary, tested)` and after that was possible to boot ``5.19.0-45-generic` in normal mode

Comment: @555Russich Kernel version in my case is `5.15.0-75-generic`.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that a reboot seems to have solved the issue. After the reboot, Ubuntu had switched to the Xorg driver, which may indicate that temporarily switching to the Xorg driver may be necessary.

It then required yet another reboot for the 530 driver version to actually become active and properly appear in `nvidia-smi`.

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/335293/161463) may be also helpful in the context of debugging the problem.

Comment: Does `nvidia-smi` report that 530 was installed? I believe that 530 is a transitional package to 535 now