# How do I revert back to legacy drivers, or use the new drivers? I have a NVIDIA GT 620, and cannot boot into Ubuntu

Tags: nvidia

It's showing me:

```
[ FAILED] Failed to start Process Error reports when automatic reporting is enabled 

The NVIDIA GeForce GT 620 GPU installed in the system is supported through the NVIDIA 390.xx Legacy drivers. Please visit http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html for more information. The 535.154.05 NVIDIA driver will ignore this GPU. Continuing probe...
```

I can boot into TTY#s, but they keep on getting overridden by the NVRM messages.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't search hard enough, and I followed this guide.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change proprietary video driver using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335285/how-to-change-proprietary-video-driver-using-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tool called `ubuntu-drivers` that lets you list and switch all available drivers.

```
$ ubuntu-drivers
Usage: ubuntu-drivers [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --gpgpu              gpgpu drivers
  --free-only          Only consider free packages
  --package-list PATH  Create file with list of installed packages (in install mode)
  --no-oem             Do not include OEM enablement packages (these enable an external archive)
  -h, --help           Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  debug        Print all available information and debug data about drivers.
  devices      Show all devices which need drivers, and which packages...
  install      Install a driver [driver[:version][,driver[:version]]]
  list         Show all driver packages which apply to the current system.
  list-oem     Show all OEM enablement packages which apply to this system
```

So as long as you can get to a prompt you can switch to another driver.

Use `ubuntu-drivers --gpgpu list` (or `list-oem`) to show the available drivers and 'install' to install the chosen one.

Comment: I apologize, but I'm an extremely inexperienced Ubuntu user... how do I access that if I can't boot into it?

Comment: that is vital information but is not part of the question -) if you can not boot into Ubuntu why not ask about that? more important: where does it stop? can you at that point use control-alt-f1 to get to a login? please add those things to the question (comments are not good for that)