# Skip sign verification at module loading

Tags: kernel, security, secure-boot

With secure boot enabled, is there a way to load a custom kernel module not signed, or signed with an auto-generated private key? Trying to load my custom module, `insmod` exits with the error `Required key not available`. I tried also passing `enforcemodulesig=0` but it doesn't work.

Ubuntu version: 16.04

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Login broken after 15.10 -> 16.04 LTS upgrade, related to NVIDIA driver](http://askubuntu.com/questions/765509/login-broken-after-15-10-16-04-lts-upgrade-related-to-nvidia-driver)